# Trace insert of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My company has a process where data gets moved from one DB to a completely different DB.  When a stored procedure gets called,  it calls a bunch of other stored procedures and also passes through some triggers.  I have a value that is being inserted incorrectly and I'm just trying to find out where the value is being calculated wrong.  I tried using Profiler,  but have had little success in isolating they problem.

Is there a way to set breakpoints for every step without opening up hundreds of stored procedures and triggers and manually toggling on breakpoints on every line?

Ideally,  I'd like to only step through lines that modify a particular variable,  but I'll settle for tracing through everything.  This is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: You should be able to use Profiler to capture the inputs, which would allow you to manually execute the procedures.  Not sure about the outputs though.

Comment: I can capture the query output,  but not the state of execution... Unless there is something I don't know which is entirely possible.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might benefit from simply executing the stored proc in a debugger. You can inspect variables while the code is being stepped through.

This is probably easiest/slickest to do using Visual Studio. This is the [MS article on doing that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316549) -- it is pretty simple to do, esp. if you already know how to debug code in VS.

Comment: That's the one thing Oracle SQL Developer has over SSMS - a decent debug feature. They should either unify it with VS or put some decent debugging in it.

Comment: Wow, the one thing! Who knew? Sorry, I found your comment amusing. Seriously though, you are quite correct SSMS generally "mostly slick" , but debugging?. Now, in terms of functionality I am sure we could point out lots of Oracle goodies I suppose every tool has its quirks. For me, select from dual was always one of the Oracle head scratchers.

Comment: Thank you for the article.  That looks very promising!  I will try it out. I have used VS for debugging.